# Como usar o while no tkinter para fazer o jogo do Par ou Impar?

Tags: python, while, tkinter

eu estou começando agora e por isso estou super perdido, esse e meu código:

```
from random import choice
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.title("Jogo do PAR ou IMPAR!")
fontPadrao = ("Arial", "10", "bold")
def jogar():
    pc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    escolha = ''
    while True:
        cont = 0
        pc_escolha = choice(pc)
        pc_escolha1["text"] = pc_escolha
         jogador = int(jo.get())
         jo.delete(0, END)
         print(jogador)
         print(pc_escolha)
        while escolha != 'P' and escolha != 'I':
            escolha = str(parimpar2.get()).upper().strip()
            parimpar2.delete(0, END)
            digitar["text"] = "Informe [P]PAR ou [I]IMPAR!"
        digitar["text"] = ""
        resu = (jogador + pc_escolha) % 2
        if escolha == 'P' and resu == 0:
            vencedor["text"] = "Jogador Venceu!"
            cont += 1
        elif escolha == 'P' and resu == 1:
            vencedor["text"] = "Computador Venceu! Voce venceu {} 
vezes".format(cont)
            break
        if escolha == 'I' and resu == 1:
            vencedor["text"] = "Jogador Venceu!"
            cont += 1
        elif escolha == 'I' and resu == 0:
            vencedor["text"] = "Computador Venceu! Voce venceu {} 
vezes".format(cont)
            break            
jo = Entry(janela, width=5)
jo["bg"] = "#D3D3D3"
jo.place(x=165, y=40)

bt = Button(janela, text="Jogar", width=20, command=jogar)
            bt["font"] = ("Arial", "10", "bold")
            bt.place(x=100, y=250)

            Jogador = Label(janela, text="Jogador")
            Jogador.place(x=10, y=40)

            parimpar = Label(janela, text="Escolha PAR ou IMPAR[P/I]")
            parimpar.place(x=10, y=80)

            parimpar2 = Entry(janela, width=5)
            parimpar2["bg"] = "#D3D3D3"
            parimpar2.place(x=165,y=80)

            Computador = Label(janela, text="Computador ")
            Computador.place(x=10, y=110)

            pc_escolha1 = Label(janela, text="")
            pc_escolha1.place(x=165, y=110)

            vencedor = Label(janela, text="",  font=fontPadrao)
            vencedor.place(x=125, y=190)

            digitar = Label(janela, text="")
            digitar.place(x=10, y=140)

            janela.geometry("600x300+500+200")
            janela.mainloop()
```

E esta aparecendo esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alquem pode me ajudar????

Comment: Suponho que jo.get() está retornando algo que não é um inteiro, então o int levanta essa exceção. Seria como semelhante a int("ABC")

Comment: o que eu não e por que não ta retornado um inteiro sendo que da esse erro antes mesmo de eu colocar um novo valor

Comment: Tente trocar essa linha: `jogador = int(jo.get())`
por está, para entender melhor o que está vindo do método get do objeto jo.
```resposta = jo.get()
print(resposta)
if resposta: #faça algo
print(resposta)
else:
print(resposta)
 #não há resposta nada que resposta esteja referenciando.```

Comment: então eu fiz o que você falou e esta retornando o numero que eu digitei

Comment: Se estiver falando do número que a sua  imagem mostra, https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZMEG.png
Quase certeza que jo.get() está retornando uma string vazia e você ao tentar converter com int('') acaba gerando tal erro.
Verifique se o retorno de jo.get é uma são realmente números em forma de string ou se é uma string vazia. 
Veja como eu dupliquei o erro, somente ao tentar converter uma string vazia:
```>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```

Comment: @Luã você está preenchendo o campo "jogador", na tela?

Comment: sim, eu quero que ao fazer o loop o numero que eu digitei suma e eu possa colocar um novo valor e eu quero que esse loop continue ate o eu perder e o pc ganhar mostrando quantas vitorias consecutivas eu tive

Comment: Enquanto não resolver o fato de que jo.get() não está retornando uma string com número dentro, continuará a acompanhar este erro.
O correto na minha opinião, seria deixar de converter jo.get() para inteiro, ficando essa forma: ```... . pc_escolha1["text"] = pc_escolha
         jogador = jo.get()
         jo.delete(0, END)..```
Segundo https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/tk_entry.htm
o método get retorna uma entrada de texto -- que no seu caso está ficando como vazia. Assim o int() levanta um erro dizendo que não consegue converter string vazia em número.

Comment: eu ja pensei em tirar o int so que o problema e que na hora que o codigo chegar nessa parte resu = (jogador + pc_escolha) % 2 para verificar se e par ou impar vai dar erro

Comment: Então filtre pra saber se a entrada é válida ou seja, certifique-se que a string contém somente números para funcionar com a conversão. Tente utilizar recursos da classe string. if jo.get().isdigit(): #faça algo, confirma-se que só contém números nessa entrada. Se entrar nesse if então converta para números jogador = int(jo.get())